# Laravel Sanctum not working with Jetstream's default Login.vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum, laravel-jetstream

So I'm using Jetstream for the authorization part! Now I want to use Laravel sanctum's "auth:sanctum" middleware to protect my api's!

But when I call the api from my SPA, it gives me "401 (Unauthorized)" error even though I'm making csrf-cookie while logging in!

The api works fine when I call it from Postman by passing the token in Bearer token header!

My codes:

Login.vue: (This is where I'm creating the token)

```
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
.then(response => {
       this.form
       .transform(data => ({
            ... data,
            remember: this.form.remember ? 'on' : ''
       }))
      .post(this.route('login'), {
            onFinish: () => this.form.reset('password'),
      })
})
```

AppLayout.vue: (This is where I'm calling the api)

```
axios.get('/api/abilities',)
.then((response)=>{
    console.log(response.data);
 })
 .catch((error)=>{
     console.log(error);
 })
```

api.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/abilities', function (Request $request) {
    return auth()->user();
});
```

Other things that I've already done are:

1. Added "axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;" to bootstrap.js
2. Added "SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000;" to .env file
3. Added "EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class" to Kernel.php

Comment: So for postman you're using token-based authentication, while for your SPA you're using session-cookie based authentication?? Asking because you "EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful". Does your SPA run on a subdomain? Do you want to authenticate with a bearer-token or with laravels build in session-cookie auth?

Comment: Yes! Thats just how Sanctum works! It uses token for api's and session-cookie for SPA!
No it does not run on subdomain!
I want to use session-cookie for SPA and token for api as thats how its supposed to be used!

Comment: But where do you send your login credentials to /login?
And well, that‘s how you CAN use it. Not how it‘s supposed to be used.

Comment: It looks like you‘re getting a new CSRF Token, do something with the response which is wrong because sanctum/csrf-token doesn‘t return anything and then you send an empty post request to login.